# Is there a licensing restriction shipping proprietary software that packages/redistributes CDDL1.1-licensed software?

Tags: licensing, cddl

We are having a debate about whether we are allowed to package CDDL 1.1 licensed software like jaxb-api as-is with our commercial software. We would provide the licensing terms of CDDL 1.1 as required  and we are not making any modifications. Reading the texts at https://resources.whitesourcesoftware.com/blog-whitesource/top-10-common-development-and-distribution-license-cddl-questions-answered seems to suggest we can. Can anyone share their experience? There is also a question about whether re-distribution terms changed between CDDL 1.0 and CDDL 1.1 and while https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LEGAL-121 seems to say no in legalese, a plain-speak insight would be helpful.